# Logback for Default Package

Tags: grails, logging

I am working in Grails 3.0.9 application and I am creating services and controller in default package. I want to log them with my logger but logger asks for the package name. I want to show the logs on All level from application. I set root logger as All and booom it shows whole grails framework logs. I want only my application logs. Please suggest me a good solution for my logging problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move your classes to packages.

Comment: I have done dear but I want to learn the default package solution.